# How to test a Facebook app locally using Google App Engine

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, local

So, I know there are a lot of similar (or, let's face it, exactly the same) questions on this board. However, they're all from quite some time ago and I've tried the solutions put forth in them and they don't seem to work. I thought I'd ask it again, and preface also that I have relatively little experience so please bear with me.

I'm writing a Facebook app, and I want to be able to test it locally, but Facebook won't let me put "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 or my IP address into the "App Domains" field, so I can't use them. I only get these two errors:

```
App Domains: http://localhost:11080 should not contain protocol information.
App Domains: http://localhost:11080 is not a valid domain.
```

How can I get this to work? It's really obnoxious to have to deploy my code every time I want to change one little thing...

Let me know if you need more information from me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put localhost in  "App Domains" field instead of the complete URL.

```
App Domains: localhost
```

Comment: Oh okay, thanks! That works great (from the Facebook side). Now, I can get to my app through localhost which is very nice, but when I'm logged in the page just constantly reloads. Which I would imagine is an issue with my code, but it's the same code that works fine when live on the app engine url i have... Not sure what the deal is there.

Comment: What do you mean by "constantly reloads"? Is redirection happening in a loop? Is it happening just on localhost or on app engine as well? Check the handler of your redirect_uri and make sure there is no redirection loop there. Also, in App Domains field, you may need to add your all domains along with localhost like xxxxx.appspot.com. If you are using facebook oauth dialog, make sure that redirect_uri matches the Site URL you configured in app settings.